# question about text formatting in Vim

Tags: vim, text, formatting

I'm using Vim to write text that isn't code, just free form writing.  To do this I like to have `formatoptions` include the `w` flag and sometimes the `a` flag.

The w flag is supposed to make it so an end-of-paragraph occurs when a line ends in a non-blank character, rather than at first blank line (which is Vim default).  Here is snippet from the help docs:

```
w   Trailing white space indicates a paragraph continues in the next line.
    A line that ends in a non-white character ends a paragraph.
```

The a flag makes reformatting automatic, as you type.  For example, in document with text below and w and a flags the lines reformat as I type only up to the 'last line in paragraph' and not below.

```
This it the first line of the paragraph. <cr>
The text in it reformats properly as I type <cr>
up to the last line of the paragraph, which is <cr>
right after this line, that is, just below here: <cr>
This is the last line of paragraph.<cr>
This is the first line of second paragraph. <cr>
Even though there is no blank line between <cr>
it and first paragraph, any reformatting of <cr>
the first paragraph ends at the last line <cr>
of first paragraph.<cr>
<cr>
This the the first line after second paragraph<cr>
```

**Now to my question:**
With `a` and `w` flags the reformatting works properly as I type in the first paragraph, i.e, second paragraph remains untouched.  But sometimes I want to select the current paragraph using `vap`.  It seems to me that with the `w` flag set this should select only the first paragraph.  But in fact issuing `vap` in first paragraph selects the second paragraph also, all the way down to the blank line with `<cr>`, seemingly ignoring the `w` formatoptions flag.

Is this expected behavior?  Am I missing something?  Why does `vap` not select only the paragraph I'm in, which ends at first line with no trailing whitespace?

Comment: Vim is only really on-topic when used explicitly for programming; Help with making your wordprocessor behave falls outside the scope of Stack Overflow. Voted to move.

Comment: Hmm, well, this is for settings in a plugin that I'm writing that is definitely a programming project.  It is an application being written in VimScript that is used for writing text, as well as code. . .   Moreover, I think more of the expert Vim users are here at SO than other places, not likely to get as good an answer anywhere else.

Comment: @meagar I thought SO community already agreed that vim questions should go here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: @ZyX Going down that list, none of the quantitative bullets apply; he's not using vim as a programmers editor or IDE, he's not using VML or regular expressions. He's using a wordprocessor and looking for support.

Comment: @meagar -- Yes, I did frame my question that way, b/c that's the way that it makes most sense.  But I have several thoughts (1) as I said in previous comment I am using Vim as a programmer, (2) although I asked in context of pure text editing, same issues apply (I think) to editing of code comments in Vim, and (3) even if I were purely a word processing Vim user, what sense would it make to send my question from here to a different StackExchange site where there are very Vim users?  All the expert Vim users are here at SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the help at `:h paragraph` this does not mention the 'fo' setting. So it
looks like the fo setting does not really change, what defines a paragraph. This might be a bug or unclear documentation, so you might want to discuss this on the vim-dev mailinglist.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like what counts as a 'paragraph' for motions isn't in sync with what counts as a 'paragraph' for formatting.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz in the meantime you could try emulating a new text-object: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects

Answer (score 0):

From `:help text-objects` or `:h paragraph` you can see that a paragraph for vim begins after each empty line, and also at each of a set of paragraph macros, specified by the pairs of characters in the 'paragraphs' option. Blank lines containing only whitespace are also paragraph boundaries.

The `w` flag in formatoptions only makes a difference when autoformatting a paragraph as you type: it will split lines and leave whitespace at the end of lines which do not end a paragraph. I suppose the help text is a bit confusing.